# Python: JSON can't be decoded

Tags: python, json

I'm following along with the examples in Wes McKinney's "Python for Data Analysis".

In Chapter 2, we are asked to count the number of times each time zone appears in the 'tz' position, where some entries do not have a 'tz'. And he used data with json-format.

I am using Python 2.7 and IDE PyCharm. Data comes from [github](https://github.com/Canuckish/pydata-book/tree/master/ch02).

```
import json
path = 'usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'
open(path).readline()
records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]
records[0]
```

After that I got an error `No JSON object could be decoded`.
I validated this in [json validate](http://jsonlint.com/), but it returned an error too.
I can't understand, where is an error in this data

Comment: Why are you opening `path` twice? FWIW, `open(path).readline()` opens the file, reads a line, throws it away, then closes the file.  That file structure is a bit odd: it has a separate JSON object on each line.

Comment: Your code snippet works for me under python2.7 and python3.4 on Linux. Is it possible that during the download or saving of the file something went wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me, the full 3560 json records decode without issue. I suspect some corruption of the input file, e.g. is it truncated? (there should be 3560 lines).

Comment: Perhaps you've added an extra empty line at the end of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded the file from github, opened python 2.7, entered the above 5 lines of code. and it worked for me.

Can you please confirm that the file you are using is about 1.5MB?

The file can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d8amonk/pydata-book/master/ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt ("save page as" will save the file to your computer)

Can you please execute your code again, using full-path-name of the txt file?

```
>>> import json
>>> path = 'usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'
>>> open(path).readline()
'{ "a": "Mozilla\\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\\/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\\/17.0.963.78 Safari\\/53
5.11", "c": "US", "nk": 1, "tz": "America\\/New_York", "gr": "MA", "g": "A6qOVH", "h": "wfLQtf", "l": "orofrog", "al": "
en-US,en;q=0.8", "hh": "1.usa.gov", "r": "http:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/l\\/7AQEFzjSi\\/1.usa.gov\\/wfLQtf", "u": "http:
\\/\\/www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov\\/pubmed\\/22415991", "t": 1331923247, "hc": 1331822918, "cy": "Danvers", "ll": [ 42.576698,
-70.954903 ] }\n'
>>> records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]
>>> records[0]
{u'a': u'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.78 Safari/535.11', u
'c': u'US', u'nk': 1, u'tz': u'America/New_York', u'gr': u'MA', u'g': u'A6qOVH', u'h': u'wfLQtf', u'cy': u'Danvers', u'l
': u'orofrog', u'al': u'en-US,en;q=0.8', u'hh': u'1.usa.gov', u'r': u'http://www.facebook.com/l/7AQEFzjSi/1.usa.gov/wfLQ
tf', u'u': u'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22415991', u't': 1331923247, u'hc': 1331822918, u'll': [42.576698, -70.9
54903]}
>>>
```

Comment: thank you. I think I had some problems with file. Now It works!

Comment: You are welcome  :-)